# Python Global-variables don't change in my function

Tags: function, python-3.x, class, pygame, global-variables

I'd like to use a global variable in other files and to change the value of this variable :
settings.py :

```
mort = False
```

platforms1.py :

```
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #..........
class Spike(Platform):
player = None
def invisible(self):
    if not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player):
        self.image.set_alpha(0)
def update(self):
    global mort
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player):
        self.image.set_alpha(256)
        mort = True
        print(mort)
>>>True
```

and i can add spikes in my levels like that :
levels1.py :

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from platforms1 import *

#add a spike (image, width, height)
block = Spike(spikes,1,1)
block.rect.x = 1360 #pos en x
block.rect.y = 696 #pos en y
block.player = self.player
Spike.invisible(block)
self.background_list.add(block)
```

and added in my main loop :
main.py :

```
while mort == True:
    #.................
active_sprite_list.update()
current_level.update()
print(mort)
>>>False
```

AS u can see "mort" stay false in main.py and obvsly don't execute while mort == True: loop when in platforms1.py "mort" is True.

Idk if you need more code, I think I got the most important right here but i can paste you more if you want.

Thanks for advice and sorry for my bad english, I'm french!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
from platforms1 import *
```

you bind the objects in `platforms1` to new variables in the current module. Now you have 2 references to those objects. When code in `platforms1` rebinds its local reference (e.g., `mort = True`) the references in other modules are not affected. If you want to use the same object in multiple modules, don't do `import *`. Instead

```
import platforms1
while platforms1.mort:
    ...
```